# Is it possible to use NodeJS in sync way until some point?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have simple start function and i want that all of my code would work only when `mongoose.connect` is successful. Is it possible? Currently i get `info  - socket.io started` and only then i get exception.

```
module.exports.start = function(config) {
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    mongoose.connect(config.APP_DB, function(err) {
        if (err) 
            throw err;
    });

    var express = require(config.MODULES_DIR + 'express'),
        app = express(),
        http = require('http'),
        server = http.createServer(app),
        io = require(config.MODULES_DIR + 'socket.io').listen(server),
        db = mongoose.connection;

    server.listen(config.APP_PORT, config.APP_IP);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move all your stuff inside this callback:

```
mongoose.connect(config.APP_DB, function(err) {
    if (err) 
        throw err;

    /* Here... */
});
```

Comment: but there isn't any logic…

Comment: Yes there is. As this connect-function is asynchronous, there is no other way.